# How to convert Mouse Coordinates to local to SubScene in JavaFx 8

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, geometry

I have a main Stage in that I have a scene and that scene contains four SubScene. I want to get the mouse click coordinates local to the scene which is clicked. I know on which scene the mouse has been clicked on because all the scenes are having their individual event listeners but the coordinates i am getting is of the main Scene (of the stage). How do I convert that coordinate to local to scene.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the listeners to the individual subscenes works fine for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SubSceneClickTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            SubScene subScene = new SubScene(new StackPane(), 300, 300);
            subScene.setFill((i + i / 2) % 2 == 0 ? Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE : Color.AQUA);
            String message = "Click on subscene "+i;
            subScene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.printf("%s [%.1f, %.1f]%n", message, e.getX(), e.getY()));
            root.add(subScene, i / 2, i % 2);
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it give the event coordinates local to the subScene or the main stage Scene? Sorry I can't try it right now.

Comment: To the `subScene`. Wasn't that what you were asking? `MouseEvent.getX()` and `getY()` are always in the coordinate system of the node on which the listener was registered.

Comment: Yes that's what I was asking, but the mouse event you get from listener, provides global (main stage/scene) coordinates even if it's registered to any specific subScene. Thats what I got from listener. I'll try this code also soon.

Comment: No it doesn't. It gets coordinates from the node with which it's registered

Comment: Thank you so much James_D, It does gives the local to subScene coordinates. And now I understand where I was making the mistake. I was this method addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, mouseEventHandler); To add the listener.

Comment: But now there's another problem, On click, if the pick result is subScene then only the coordinates are local to scene and if there is any other node or Group containing other node inside the subscene, then if pick result is any node other than subScene, the coordinates are not local to subscene, Thanks.